# Error In Nhibernate Mapping

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate

At Run Time I got This Error pet is not mapped..
 In My Following Code :-

```
using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    IQuery query = session.CreateQuery("from pet where PetName='S.J.'");
    pet pets = query.List<pet>()[0];
    session.Delete(pets);
    transaction.Commit();
}
```

Comment: I can imagine that you have an error, but what is your question? Because you use nhibernate not correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your "pet" to "Pet" in your query . I hope it fixes the problem.

```
IQuery query = session.CreateQuery("from Pet where PetName='S.J.'");
```

Answer (score 1):

I avoid of using hql or sql when use NHibernate. Strongly-typed queries are great.
It seems that the next code would do what you want.

```
using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    var pets = session
        .QueryOver<Pet>()
        .Where(p => p.PetName == "S.J.")
        .List();
    foreach (var pet in pets){
        session.Delete(pet);
    }
    transaction.Commit();
}
```

Comment: Also check your mappings to be sure that class Pet is mapped.